# problem with saving the plot savefig in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

i didn't find how to `savefig` with that kind of code `table.plot` and the type of the table is a `DataFrame`

````
table=pd.DataFrame(ycon[att[0]])        
table[att[0]]=pd.to_numeric(table[att[0]],downcast='float',errors='coerce')
table.plot()
```
````

Comment: Did you try `plt.savefig()`?

Comment: works better if you prepared your data and then plot it with 'plt.plot' or else,,, combining with pandas is kind of complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table.plot returns a matplotlib.pyplot.axes object.

```
table=pd.DataFrame(ycon[att[0]])        
table[att[0]]=pd.to_numeric(table[att[0]],downcast='float',errors='coerce')
ax = table.plot()
fig = ax.get_figure()
fig.savefig('/path/to/figure.pdf')
```